# How to pass a variable in SQL query update

Tags: sql, delphi, fastreport

I'm a beginer in Fasreport and use a software with fastreport integrated I would like to make a report to allow the user to define 2 parameters on an easy way instead of having to open SQL Manager and change this 2 values by hand. I succeed to make the connexion with the database, request both values and show them on a dialogbox with 2 fields where the user can enter his new values. by validating the dialogbox, I would write both values back in the database. To do that I used a DBquery with the following request

```
UPDATE SupplParams
     SET StartTime = :BTIME, EndTime = :ETIME 
     WHERE ConfigNr = '0'
```

But this doesn't work

If I write the query as follows:

```
UPDATE SupplParams
SET StartTime = '0200', EndTime = '2359' 
WHERE ConfigNr = '0'
```

It works I can also print STIME and ETIME in the report, that means the values of both variables is correct.

I can share the fastreport used if needed.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MQlM.png)

Comment: Is this just SQL code or are you using FastReport for something, possibly some UI of theirs?  This looks like standard SQL syntax until you hit the "=:" which wouldn't be valid in SQL context ... it's also typically used to assign, not grab a variable's value.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, yes it's in fastreport.  THe same query with select instead of update works.

Comment: @DedeLaMouche did you say that this query is used in FastReports ?, Why would you use an update for a Report ?, it doesn't return any results, it modifies the database. If you call it before opening the report, it would be helpful to see your Delphi code calling it to check how you manage that parameter.

Comment: Which component are you using? Is it FireDAC, ADO? This `UPDATE` is inside the delphi code or are you using this `UPDATE` inside an `EXECUTE BLOCK` or something like that?

Comment: You need to edit your q to state exactly how you are executing the script and, if it is in Delphi code, show the code.  Meanwhile I'm voting to close the q because it should include this info (see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) but does not.

Comment: I succeeded to update the fields in the MS SQL database using a stored procedure and calling it and passing values in a FDquery. " exec  ModifProdTime '1234' , '5678' " but as soon i use variables instead of text, it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you using a any type of a query component, this generaly its works:

```
YourQuery.Close;
YourQuery.ParamByName('VARNAME').AsString := '1234';
YourQuery.Open; // or YourQuery.ExecSQL;
```